# How to check azure resource usage?

Tags: azure

The company I work for moved almost everything to azure, and we end up to have hundred of resources (web apps, storage account etc).

Now we would like to see if these resources are indeed needed (i.e. is there anyone really using these resources)?

Is there an easier way to check incoming requests for all these resoruces other than manually go to each resources and check on azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Azure Advisor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/advisor/) to get advice on where resources could be resized, optimized etc.